# Plaid.com the login details of this item have changed (credentials, MFA, or required user action)

Tags: plaid

I have a case open with Plaid support, but it has not been even touched since opening 12/26, perhaps they are just all on vacation for the last week.

We had use the prior API for a site and wanted to use it for a new site. We found the API has drastically changed since the last time, as year ago, and have everything seeming to work in the sandbox, but for "development" or "production" cannot get the TD Business Direct to link up and produce the needed access_token so we can pull transactions into our application.

So I am hopeful with the post I may get some help knowing what the error of "the login details of this item have changed (credentials, MFA, or required user action) and a user login is required to update this information. use Link's update mode to restore the item to a good state" really means. The Plaid Link flow seems to accept the initial credentials and the responses to MFA, but after the second question is answered gives the error and we are not able to link the account.

We see a 400 status when it tries to post out after the second MFA question is answered and shows:

{
  "display_message": null,
  "error_code": "ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED",
  "error_message": "the login details of this item have changed (credentials, MFA, or required user action) and a user login is required to update this information. use Link's update mode to restore the item to a good state",
  "error_type": "ITEM_ERROR",
  "request_id": "request_id_here"
}

Other details when we exit that may be helpful:

{"institution":{"name":"TD Bank - Business Direct","institution_id":"ins_107836"},"request_id":"request_id_here","link_session_id":"session_id_here","status":"requires_questions"}

From just reading the message would seem we may not have entered the right credentials, but we can login to the bank site just fine, so they are right and the account is not locked out.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? Did update mode work?

Answer (score 3):

When I've faced the similar issue, the reason was in changed user's details. Every time some details changed, you'll need to re-link user's bank account with plaid in update mode.

Exception with `"error_code": "ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED"` will help you detect such cases and handle them appropriately.

They have more info in their docs: https://plaid.com/docs/link/update-mode/

Comment: This is so helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

Link update should work fine. If you are facing some issues further, then create a support ticket to plaid and let them know that request id, bank_id and what type of error you are getting.

Sometimes the issue is on their side. There are quite slow in responding but you will get reply within 2 days and if there is some fix, they would ask you to test it after the fix is pushed on their side.